# How to increase the hadoop filesystem size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to perform Wordcount on a file of 10gb in hadoop  ,but hadoop does not allow as the max capcaity of hadoop is 8gb .I have also tried installing hadoop on a 1tB drive but still it shows total memory as 8gb instead of 1tb?can anyone provide a solution

Comment: are you talking about dfs block size of Data Node OR RAM size for Node Manager? What is the parameter you changed which did not work?

Comment: can you provide your changes in question? ( File name, property name and property value)